# Oracle Form 11g Performance Load Testing

Tags: oracle11g, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm testing an Oracle forms application that opens in IE.
The forms application runs on the Oracle application server using a JWM

My question is what Performance Testing Tool could be used to test an application, in particular load testing.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout AuraTester. [more information here](http://www.auraplayer.com/auratester)

It does functional and load testing of Oracle Forms using Jmeter and Junit in Eclipse.
I know that Radviews tool Webload also provides a great load testing solution. Complete with reports and a full tool. More information here:
http://radview.com/solution/oracle-forms-load-testing/

Comment: Do you have any experience of using the above?
At present we have tried webload and it does not support our software structure.